# ASP.Net WebAPI 2 404 Error - Insights Say Different

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I understand that this question has been asked several times already and I have looked at a lot of the questions, but none of the answers have worked for me thus far.

I am working with an ASP.Net WebAPI 2 Controller using .Net 4.5.2 and posting using Ajax.

I immediately get a 404 error, however looking at insights it shows that there are x amount of requests to that controller and that action\method but its returning a 404 immediately.

This is the the method, and would be grateful if anyone could help me.

```
 [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost()]

 public int InsertRecord(Models.Person model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var person = new Person
            {
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(model.DateOfBirth)
            };

            _dbContext.People.Add(person);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            var id = person.P_id;

            return id;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Data", null);
        }
    }
```

which is being called from my Ajax as follows;

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function () {

    $('#FirstName').valid();
    $('#LastName').valid();
    $('#DateOfBirth').valid();

    if ($('#FirstName').valid() &&
        $('#LastName').valid() &&
        $('#DateOfBirth').valid()) {
        //console.log("save clicked");
        var jsonData = {
            firstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
            lastName: $('#LastName').val(),
            dateofBirth: $('#DateOfBirth').val()
        }

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method  
                url: "http://localhost:56658/AddPerson/InsertRecord", // Controller/View   
                data: jsonData,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response != null && response.success) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    } else {
                        // DoSomethingElse()
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("error!");  // 
                    console.log(response);
                }

            });
        return false;
    }



});
```

Edit

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AddPerson",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "AddPerson", action = "InsertRecord"}
        );
    }
}
```

Edit 2

This is the global asax file contents

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    }
```

Edit 3

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using MVC attribute in web api?

Comment: [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost()]

Comment: you need to use **System.Web.Http.HttpPost** instead of **System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost** in web api

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder same result

Comment: @ParvSharma I have changed that but stlil getting the same result

Comment: Please post code for your routerconfig. I think your route is not configured properly

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder I have added this now

Comment: @CodeWarrior, your routeconfig is for mvc not for web api.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147268/discussion-between-code-warrior-and-jayakrishnan-gounder).

Comment: This was the default that was provided by VS when I setup the API project

Comment: Yes, just seen there is an ApiConfig now

Comment: so what would i need the rout config to look like to hit my action \ method

Comment: and i guess I need the ajax url to look more like this `url: "http://localhost:56658/api/AddPerson/InsertRecord"`

Comment: @CodeWarrior, exactly but then also can you post the code for api config

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder added under edit three

Answer (score 0):

As this is suppose to be a Wep API it should try to follow that design intent

Check for `WebApiConfic` where there is usually

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Notice the `api` prefix of the default route. This configures how web API endpoints will be called. The `api` prefix is to avoid route conflicts with the normal MVC framework.

Url would end looking like `api/AddPerson`

next make sure controller is create properly and follows suggested design. Try to avoid adding too many responsibilities to the controller. Controllers are a UI concern and should be as lean as possible.

```
public interface IAddPersonCommand {
    int? InsertRecord(Models.Person model model);
}

public class PersonController : ApiController {
    private readonly IAddPersonCommand service;
    public PersonController(IAddPersonCommand service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Models.Person model) {    
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            var id = service.InsertRecord(model);
            if(id !=null) {
                return Ok(id);
            }
        } 
        //If we get this far bad request
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: So in my uinit tests this completely breaks now, with the IHTTPActionResult i get errors in the ContentNegotiator, Formatters and Request